Asymptotics for limits of functions in many variable
A stupid question perhaps.
When dealing with limits of functions in many variables, can I use asymptotic estimations?
For example, can I just say $\sin(xy) \sim xy$ as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$ or is it a wrong way to proceed?
Why is it wrong, in case? I am thinking of something like counterexamples but I cannot invent any.
Thank you!

You frame this as a multivariable problem, but I believe that's merely complicating things. It's already a clear problem in single-variable limits.
The way Calculus is typically taught, the main risk is that every time you use $\sin x\sim x$ you're really applying the limit statement
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
and so it's best to proceed carefully, using algebra to rewrite your limit until you can split it apart using limit properties to apply the limit statements you know.
However, the way I like to think of your question is, "When is the approximation $\sin x\sim x$ not good enough?" In this case, it's quite precisely, "When $\sin x\sim x-\frac16x^3$ is better." That is, when you need to use more terms of the Taylor series for sine to evaluate it.
Consider
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3} &= -\frac16
\end{align*}
(Here's W|A for reference.)
If you replace $\sin x$ with $x$ in that expression, it's indeterminate. It's not good enough. So you need to instead approximate $\sin x\sim x-\frac16 x^3$, and then you get a determinate answer. If you want to be rigorous about it, my recommendation is to use big-O notation instead of an approximation:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3} \\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)\right)-x}{x^3} \\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)}{x^3} \\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(-\frac16+O(x^2)\right) \\
&= -\frac16
\end{align*}
In those steps, until the limit disappears, the limit is not being applied at all. The expressions within the limit are algebraically, exactly, equal to each other. The big-O just lets me avoid writing out the terms that don't affect the final result.
Similar things happen in the multivariable case, just more complicated because you'll be considering path-dependence as well. Big-O notation resolves the issues there just as rigorously.
To be clear, I'm not saying this method of approximation will always get you the answers you seek — there are times where it will muddy the waters, such as if the sine is within a logarithm, root, etc. But as far as "If it gets me an answer, is there any time I shouldn't believe that answer?" the answer to your question is squarely, "Sometimes. To believe your answer, try to prove that the remaining terms of the Taylor series cannot affect your result." And that's what big-O notation is for.

Thank you! Really clear!
